# How to create markup for FAQ component in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

How to create Microdata markup for FAQ component when the page itself is not FAQ?

The following example is based on Google Microdata https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage but Rich Results Tool (https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) doesn't seem to recognize that at all. Unless HTML root element has additional attributes `<html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">`, only in that case it works. But I would prefer to have Microdata FAQs (with different content) also on some other page types so these pages will have different itemtype on root.

```
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Question 1</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <div itemprop="text">
            Text text text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Question 2</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <div itemprop="text">
            Text text text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage"> 
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Question 1</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <div itemprop="text">
            Text text text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Question 2</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
        <div itemprop="text">
            Text text text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: U know if i can add more than one
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage"> on same page?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the source code. In any case, you can create a structured hierarchy that requires only one type FAQ.

Comment: I got an error in Google's rich results testing tool when adding a secondFAQPage blocks -- I resorted to using LD+JSON instead, combining all the FAQs on the page into one.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [{
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 1",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "Answer 1"
        }
      }, {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 2",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "Answer 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Question 3",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "Answer 3"
        }
      }]
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. Although I would prefer Microdata, surely it should be possible. It is much easier to just add a few attributes on existing HTML, code is cleaner without duplicating and easier to maintain.